# Can I get a specific version of a Secrets Manager secret in an ECS task definition?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager

I’ve stored a secret using AWS Secrets Manager. I’m trying to retrieve the secret as an environment variable in an ECS task definition.

Following [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html#secrets-create-taskdefinition), I’ve created an ECS task definition that includes the following section:

```
"secrets": [
  {
    "name": "MY_PASSWORD",
    "valueFrom": "/aws/reference/secretsmanager/my_password"
  }
],
```

As I understand it, when my task starts, this:

1. Fetches the latest version of the secret `my_password` from Secrets Manager
2. Decrypts it inside the task
3. Assigns it to the environment variable `MY_PASSWORD`

I’d like to load a **specific version** of the secret in my task definition, so changing the secret would mean creating a new task definition.

Can I do that?

---

I’ve searched on Google but couldn’t find anybody else trying to do this.

I tried appending the version ID to the `valueFrom` parameter, i.e.

```
"secrets": [
  {
    "name": "MY_PASSWORD",
    "valueFrom": "/aws/reference/secretsmanager/my_password:39231735-0279-4093-b8d1-7acd5a467295"
  }
],
```

but that got an error:

> The Systems Manager parameter name specified for secret es_username is invalid. The parameter name can be up to 2048 characters and include the following letters and symbols: a-zA-Z0-9_.-,

Comment: Hi, I know this is so late, but did you solve this issue? I can't get past this error it keeps yelling at my secret that is defined this way

Comment: The error message was misleading for me. There was no issue with the "name" - I had an error in the "valueFrom" field. Perhaps this information might help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

As per the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html), We should pass the Secrets ARN to get this worked.

**Syntax:**

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [{
        "secrets": [{
            "name": "environment_variable_name",
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:secret_name"
        }]
    }]
}
```

In order to get the specific version of the secret, you can pass the staging label or specific version ID.

**Example using Staging Label:**

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "environment_variable_name",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:secret_name::AWSPREVIOUS:"
    }]
  }]
}
```

**Example using Version ID:**

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "environment_variable_name",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:secret_name:::VersionID"
    }]
  }]
}
```